# ajax textbox watermark

Tags: asp.net, html, css, ajax

I've developed one page where i need to enter email and password ,and before typing it should display "enter your email" text in one text box and "enter your password" text in another text box.

Below is the code to perform above operation.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>lksdjflk</title>
<style>
    .unwatermarked { 
        height:18px;
        width:148px;
 }

     .watermarked { 
        height:20px;
        width:150px;
        padding:2px 0 0 2px;
        border:1px solid #BEBEBE;
        background-color:#F0F8FF;
        color:Gray;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="unwatermarked"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server"  
    Enabled="true" TargetControlID="TextBox1"  WatermarkCssClass="watermarked"    
    WatermarkText="email-Id">
</asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
</asp:Content>
```

If anyone knows any solution please let me know as soon possible.

Thanks,
Avnish

Comment: If you can use HTML5, you could take profit of the [`placeholder`](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) attribute instead.

Comment: @XaviLópez — From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute): *The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set labels inside textfields for username and password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536491/how-to-set-labels-inside-textfields-for-username-and-password)

Comment: @Quentin Not sure how the OP specifies he wants a label. _*before typing* it should display "enter your email" text in one text box and "enter your password" text in another text box_ seems a clear use case of a placeholder to me. Anyway, the question might be unclear,  and maybe the OP should pronounce on this.

Comment: @XaviLópez — The example text strongly implies it.

Comment: @Quentin I'll trust you in this one, after all, I'm not familiar at all with ASP ;)

Comment: Implies and IS are two entirely different things, one requires an assumption and no one but the OP is in the position to make that assumption Quentin.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="passwordId" runat="server"
  placeholder="Please enter UserName"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="usernameId" runat="server"
  placeholder="Please enter password"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute): *The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.*

Comment: He is asking for a particular visual effect. There are various ways to achieve it, some of them don't violate the HTML specification and are less inaccessible then this.

Comment: Again, you're assuming what the OP is going to do and not what he asked. The placeholder is there for a reason, displaying text to the user is that reason. Ranjith nor I said to do this in place of a label, you're downvoting people based on YOUR assumptions of the use of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the Placeholder for this, be warned not all browsers (earlier browsers) will support it, but it works in most common browsers. Visual studio will also report it as an error in the code lol.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Placeholder="enter some text here" CssClass="unwatermarked"></asp:TextBox>
```

You could also enter the text as an actual value then use jQuery to select it all on focus

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" value="enter some text here" CssClass="unwatermarked"></asp:TextBox>

$("#TextBox1").on("click",function() {
    $(this).select();
});
```

Comment: From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute): *The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.*

Comment: Read the actual answer.... Sometimes I wonder why I waste my time here with so many people that click without reading.

Comment: I've read the actual answer. It uses the placeholder attribute as a label. The second version uses the value attribute as one which is, arguably, worse.

Comment: Your choice, either answer works, both work in new browsers, the second works in all browsers that can run jQuery (read all browsers that matter). Not everywhere is perfect for using a label and sometimes DESIGN takes precedence over strict coding specifications. The OP asked a question which I answered validly. And NO WHERE did I say this can't be done WITH a label......

Comment: Before violating the specification, understand why it is there. Having "labels" which vanish when focused is not a good idea. Having "labels" which don't appear at all in older browsers is not a good idea. Having "labels" which aren't read out by screen readers is not a good idea (and may violate local disability discrimination laws).

Comment: You downvoted two answers that just answered the question. NEITHER said don't use a label, they just answered the question. You assume what the OP is going to do and downvote the answer? Show me in my code where I said do this in place of labeling the input please?

Comment: @ Rick please give example with ajax textbox watermark control.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `AjaxControlToolkit` you first need to register assembly in web.config or in individual page. For you case add

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="act" %>
```

to the top of your page below `Page` directive and use `TextBoxWatermarkExtender` as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="unwatermarked"></asp:TextBox>
        <act:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server"
            Enabled="true" TargetControlID="TextBox1" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" WatermarkText="Enter your email id">
        </act:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="unwatermarked"></asp:TextBox>
        <act:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender2" runat="server"
            Enabled="true" TargetControlID="TextBox2" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" WatermarkText="Enter your password">
        </act:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```

Comment: this code is not working properly please give  something else

Comment: @ Ken that code is running properly but not show message in text box at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code it's perfect, the only mistake it's here:

"asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender" it should be: "ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender"

Of course you have to open the Nuget Package Manager and install AjaxControllToolkit in your project.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TextBoxWatermark.aspx.cs" Inherits="ControlesAjax2.TextBoxWatermark" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .unwatermarked {
            height: 18px;
            width: 148px;
        }

        .watermarked {
            height: 20px;
            width: 150px;
            padding: 2px 0 0 2px;
            border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
            background-color: #F0F8FF;
            color: Gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender2" runat="server"
                Enabled="true" TargetControlID="TextBox1" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked"
                WatermarkText="email-Id"></ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx